# storing pdf on local doesnt work in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new with iPhone development.  I want to download a pdf using url and want to store it in a local folder.

Here is my code:

```
NSData *d = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.com/ebookapplication/book_pdf/20111108094614hii.pdf"]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.pdf"]; 
[d writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
NSString *myPathInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:myPathInfo toPath:path error:NULL];
}
 NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfurl];
[detail.bookweb loadRequest:requestObj];//to display data in web view
```

This code is working for display pdf in web view using url, but it doesn't work for storing pdf in our local system. Actually I want to store these downloaded pdf in one folder and and display it in library format.  Please help.

Comment: What you are meaning by `storing in local system`? You have already been stored that locally into the document folder.

Comment: storing in local system means i want store this file in my project folder on some other place from where i will able to read that files .i have searched this file in document folder but i didn't get this file.I am using xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-writeToFile:Atomically has already placed your file in the folder you've specified in the -copyItemAtPath:toPath: method, and is thus redundant.  The document was already in the documents directory folder, you then copied it over to the same directory!  I think that's your problem.

EDIT:

This Line HERE:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.pdf"];
```

specifies your path.

You can `NSLog` it with this line: `NSLog(@"Document Path = %@", path);`

As for your library comment, it shouldn't be that hard.  My app, which basically does this already, wires 
AQGridView: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

And Apple's Docwatcher class from DITableView: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Listings/Classes_DITableViewController_h.html

Together to create an app that trolls the documents directory and adds files to an NSArray which are then displayed by the grid.  A simpler approach would just be to use the DITableViewController though, considering it solves your problems, it's just the grid was for a little more pizzaz.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi,I can use Docwatcher to implement library.but can you plesae tell me how can i solve my file copy problem? i want store all pdf files  in one folder.how can i set path to that folder?

Comment: but where this path get set? i mean folder name? if it is document folder i have searched files in document folder,but file is not exist there..plz help